# Java sychronized not protecting the variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Java multithreading. This is the the code I write.

```
package com.company;


public class Account  {
    private double balance = 100;

    public synchronized double getBalance() {
        synchronized (this){
            return balance;
        }
    }

    public  void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public   boolean withdraw(double amount,String name){
        if(this.getBalance()>amount){
            if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("customer0")){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " withdraw " + amount);
            System.out.println("Hello,  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " You current balance is " + this.getBalance());

            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". Your current balance is " + this.getBalance() + " and you  cannot withdraw " + amount);
            //System.out.println("Welcome,  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Your current balance is " + this.getBalance());

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the main class

```
package com.company;

import org.omg.PortableServer.THREAD_POLICY_ID;


public class Main implements Runnable {
    Account account = new Account();
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Main main = new Main();
            for(int i= 0; i< 2; i++) {
                Thread c1 = new Thread(main, "customer" + i);
                c1.start();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "'s balance is " + account.getBalance());
        account.withdraw(60, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //
    }
}
```

I put synchronized keyword at getBalance() to make sure it can be accessible only by one thread a time. But still I get the negative balance.

```
customer0's balance is 100.0
customer1's balance is 100.0
customer1 withdraw 60.0
Hello,  customer1 You current balance is 40.0
customer0 withdraw 60.0
Hello,  customer0 You current balance is -20.0
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be synchronizing the writes?

Comment: On a side note, don't use `double` for precision important values like money.

Comment: As Juan mentioned, you should synchronize the writes instead of synchronizing the get. No need to use synchronized for getBalance

Comment: @CeilingGecko, if not double then what should one use, throw some light on that. That would be of great help

Comment: @user2900314 `BigDecimal`, for example.

Comment: @ILoveCoding are you suggesting the usage of BigDecimal as it has better precision than double? or some thing else.

Comment: @user2900314 `BigDecimal` has better precision than double, yes, because it does not work as a regular floating point would work (which `double` does). More info [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be synchronizing withdraw *and* balance.

Your code just now could let two threads withdraw at the same time but not let them check the balance at the same time.

You only want **one** thread withdrawing & **one** thread checking the balance at one time.

(Thanks for the edit suggestions)

Comment: You should synchronize both.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I second you. He should be synchronize on both getter and setter.

Comment: @talex True, I hadn't look to closely at all the code.

Comment: @TheLostMind Withdraw needs to be synchronized as well, to guard the TOCTTOU (Time of Check To Time of Use (Update)) gap.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Ya. You are right. TOCTTOU is indeed critical :P. One thread could read a value and go inside `if` block  and another could come and ruin it all :)